# avoid creating dialog wrapper components in angular

Tags: angular, viewchild, mat-dialog

I'm using angular material to open dialogs. I have a lot of components that are getting openend in dialogs but as a matter of good separation of concerns I want to avoid baking in dialog behavior to the compoent. 
I have have a wrapper component call dashboard-dialog that has a ng-content area and provides some basic functionality and styling.

I would love to be able to do something like this like I could do with tsx/react;

```
const dialogComp = `<app-dashboard-dialog><app-create-user-form (create)="handleCreate()" cancel="handleCancel()"></app-create-user-form></app-dashboard-dialog>`
this.dialog.open(dialogComp, { ... });
```

**Is there anything like this that will work with mat-dialog?  How can I avoid making a dialog wrapped version of a component when we decide to open the component in a dialog?**

Currently I am creating a new dialog component ex create-user-form-dialog.component.ts that has same template as my wished for dialogComp variable.
and now opening this new dialog component this.dialog.open(CreateUserFormDialog, { ... });

The dialog component has the dialog ref and data injected.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-create-user-form-dialog',
    template: `
        <app-dashboard-dialog #dialog>
            <app-create-user-form
                [detail]="injected_detail"
                (create)="createUser($event)"
                (cancel)="cancel($event)"
            >
            </app-create-user-form>
        </app-dashboard-dialog>
    `,
    styleUrls: []
})

export class CreateUserFormDialogComponent {
    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CreateUserFormDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public injected_detail: Info
    ) {}
```

So create-user-form.component.ts emits out the results of its buttons (save, cancel etc) and create-user-form-dialog.component.ts spits things back out via the dialogref.close method.  Not sure how this complicates the situation and if ViewChild can still be used in some way.

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://medium.com/@karsonbraaten/reducing-boilerplate-code-when-using-angular-material-dialog-d27f436072d5) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I did something like this for a project recently. You have to inject the component you want to display in the dialog, and then set up a service to relay the response back to the component that launched the dialog, because you can't use inputs or outputs. It's a lot of effort initially, but it is possible, and you do end up with just one dialog component. I'll see if I can do an example...

Comment: Any luck with the below @Ken?